# Multiple datasource for one model

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I had one database from which I was taking the data in my spring boot microservice loading that into a Request[Model] object. Now I have 2 database both contains the same type of data. How can i use multiple databases in spring boot under one model only.

Comment: I am downvoting this due to lack of effort - a simple google search `spring boot multiple datasources` and clicking the first search result would provide the answer https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: I am looking for one model multiple databases not multiple model multiple databases. In this example they are using user for user database and product for product database. I want user model for both databases.

Comment: that doesnt change the technical implementation of having 2 datasource beans and programattically setting and using the one u need. Define a DDL definition in an sql file and have it run at startup in a postconstruct bean to populate both databases.

Comment: i tried that baeldung solution but as i am trying to implement that for one model i am getting null pointer exeception. How it will decide when to use which database or it query both databases each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. You have to create 2 Entity manager, 2 Transaction manager, 2 Datasource config classes and 2 Repository in 2 different folders. Here is my code

https://github.com/j-arpit/MULTIDATABASE.git